# SQL query using pyodbc where the selected data is in a dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas, t-sql, pyodbc

What is the most efficient way to query my SQL (T-SQL) database when I want to inner join the queried data onto a pandas dataframe afterwards?

I don't know how to pass information into SQL from Python via a PYODBC query so my current best idea is to form the query in a way that I know aligns with my Python dataframe (i.e. I know all the information has STARTDATE > 2016, so it's easy for me to request that, and I know that PRODUCT = Private_Car). However if I use:

```
SELECT *
FROM rmrClaim
WHERE (PRODUCT = 'Private_Car') AND (YEAR >= 2016)
```

I am still going to bring in far more data than necessary. What I would rather be able to do is select only data which contains my merge key (ID) from the SQL DB.

Is there a more efficient way to query the DB so that given a pandas dataframe I can only bring the data which I will need for inner joining afterwards?
Can I pass a list from python into a sql query using PYODBC?

Edit - Trying to phrase differently:

I have a dataframe from CSV (dataframe A), and I want to take data from my SQL DB to produce a dataframe (dataframe B). The data in my SQL DB is much much larger than the data in dataframe A so I want to be able to send a SQL query which only requests data that is within dataframe A so that I don't end up with a dataframe B which is 10x larger than dataframe A. My current idea for this is to use knowledge I have of dataframe A (i.e. that all of the data in dataframe A is after 2016) however if there is a way to pass a list into my SQL query I can more efficiently query a subset of data

Comment: use the pymssql and write your query before passing it to pandas dataframe. do you need an example?

Comment: "so I want to be able to send a SQL query which only requests data that is within dataframe A" - I'm confused. If you really need to LEFT JOIN the data you retrieve with your DataFrame rows then by definition your SQL query will need to retrieve rows that are *not* within the DataFrame. If you only want to retrieve rows that will match the rows in the DataFrame then an INNER JOIN would be sufficient.

Comment: @Gord Thompson, you are correct an inner join is correct. The question is around how to retrieve data from the SQL DB which make an inner join perfectly match ID from SQL DB to the ID from my csv, without bringing extra data across. Corrected the main post.

Answer (score 0):

use the `pyodbc` and write your query before passing it to pandas dataframe. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
connstr = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=MSSQLSERVER;Database=Claims;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM rmrClaim WHERE (PRODUCT = 'Private_Car') AND (YEAR >= 2016) AND ID in {} ".format(dfA.Column), pyodbc.connect(connstr))
df
```

Comment: I am using Pyodbc instead of pymssql but it seems the same. So this is essentially what my current solution is, but here I am bringing all of the information from the database into a dataframe. The problem is that it is 10x the data I require. I have a different dataframe in Python currently which I wish to join data from the SQL DB onto. I am looking for a way to select data from the SQL DB where it aligns with the data in my previous (already in Python) dataframe.

Comment: i am really not clear what you mean. you can join two dataframes using merge and common columns. Maybe rephrase the question. show samples of the two dataframes you are trying to merge.

Comment: I have a dataframe from CSV (dataframe A), and I want to take data from my SQL DB to produce a dataframe (dataframe B). The data in my SQL DB is much much larger than the data in dataframe A so I want to be able to send a SQL query which only requests data that is within dataframe A so that I don't end up with a dataframe B which is 10x larger than dataframe A. 

My current idea for this is to use knowledge I have of dataframe A (i.e. that all of the data in dataframe A is after 2016) however if there is a way to pass a list into my SQL query I can more efficiently query a subset of data

Comment: Okay, I get you now. You can actually pass a column into the SQLDB query to filter by say ID. See a modification I made in the answer using the tuple function.

Comment: This seems like the right answer, I am getting a problem (TypeError: Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly). I tried using +str(tuple(dfA.Column) and still no success. Any idea how I can get around this?

Comment: Okay, I have modified it. Have a look. let me know if it works.

Comment: It feels like this is the right path, still no success however, new error: 

Name: Column, dtype: int64': ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'Column'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

I have renamed Column for anonymity, but it is the correct name on my machine

Comment: I need to see your script especially around pd.read_sql. It seems like you are not building the right query for SQL to process. normally it should include the 'in' clause and then a list.

Comment: (cc: @Violatic) `WHERE (PRODUCT = 'Private_Car') AND (YEAR >= 2016) ID in ...` is missing an AND. Should be `WHERE (PRODUCT = 'Private_Car') AND (YEAR >= 2016) AND ID in ...`

Comment: Thanks @GordThompson, I have modified the SQL query. Note the AND in the  "AND ID in {}".